# MongoDB IntelliJ: How to configure custom jar project from my war project

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I work with IntelliJ, Spring, Maven, Tomcat7 and MongoDB

I have 2 projects:

- JAR: this should be an auth service
- WAR: this has my auth service as a dependency

Now I have following bean configuration in my war project:

```
    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="jwt" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ProjectDB" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions
         thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <!-- ########################################################################### -->
    <!-- Configuration for auth -->
    <!-- ########################################################################### -->

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="auth" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ProjectDB-auth" />
    </bean>
```

My WAR project should use ProjectDB and auth service the ProjectDB-auth

- Injection in my WAR project -> `@Autowired private MongoTemplate jwt;`
- Injection in my JAR project -> `@Autowired private MongoTemplate auth;`

This works fine, but I have an other mongoDB configuration XML file in my JAR project which will be completely ignored (will be never imported in my application context).

```
    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="test" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="AuthDBBase-notInUse" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions
         thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

I need to remove this file, but then IntelliJ can not resolve dependency for `@Autowired private MongoTemplate auth;`

I think everything is wrong with my configuration although this works correctly. But how to configure both my projects the right way?

Comment: What do you mean by “everything is wrong”? Perhaps “nothing is wrong” instead?

Comment: Sorry my fail, i mean something is wrong in my configuration :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything is perfectly OK with your setup.

You want to create a JAR to be used by any client, in this case your WAR. You have a dependency on a database. You can leave this dependency undeclared by omitting any Spring configuration in the JAR. This would not be clean. Also, your IDE complains because it cannot check the validity of your project.

It is better to declare that dependency, quite similar to header files in C or Maven dependencies with scope `provided`. Add that Spring configuration to the project as you did. Tell the users of your library to either include that configuration into their own, or to use that configuration as documentation to see which beans just *need* to exist for your artifact to work.